# Entity Framework: Recovered connectivity still yields 11001 error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, database-connection

I'm doing some error recovery with Entity Framework and SQL Server. I want my application to reload information in the background after connectivity with the database has been restored.

My test scenario:

- put my machine in Airplane Mode
- start the application; expected error: (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)
- the application will retry connecting every 5 seconds by executing a query using entity framework
- turn off airplane mode
- after 10+ attempts; the same error remains: (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)

This persuades me to believe executing a query will not try to open a new transport level connection after connectivity has been restored.

Is there any way to tell Entity Framework (or ADO.NET) to attempt to reopen a connection?

**Update:** Since I'm using Entity Framework 6, I can use [SqlAzureExecutionStrategy](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Connection%20Resiliency%20Spec) instead of a hand-coded or enterprise library retry policy.

Comment: I'd think creating a new instance of your `DBContext` would recreate the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
private static void TryToConnect(DbContext dbContext, int connectionCounter)
{
  // in ConnectionString you can set the Connect Timeout = 5000; OR

  // IN CODE:
  // var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext;
  // var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
  // objectContext.CommandTimeout = 5000;

  try
  {
    dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (connectionCounter < 10)
    {
      TryToConnect(dbContext, connectionCounter++);
    }
    else
    {
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

From outside you can call it like: `TryToConnect(myDbContext, 0);`

Comment: @BasBrekelmans If you wana to do it very proffesional check this link :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680905(v=pandp.50).aspx Doei

Comment: Solved it using the SqlAzureExecutionStrategy as explained in my updated question. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

All you should need to do is re-instantiate your `DBContext`. Not sure if this is acceptable for your scenario. I've tested this and the connection is re-created as expected.

Looking at the source code for `DBContext`, we can see that re-instantiating the object does re-create the connection:

```
protected DbContext()
{
    this.InitializeLazyInternalContext(new LazyInternalConnection(this.GetType().DatabaseName()), null);
}
```

That said, [Bassam Alugili's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19567359/1324019) is probably preferable, unless you gain something else by re-initializing the entire dbcontext.

Comment: +1 there is a lot of ways to that he can just use also the Retry pattern of the Microsoft Enterprise libary and combined with your code.